# c# Get File Name

Tags: c#, string, filenames

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        OpenFileDialog newOpen = new OpenFileDialog();

       DialogResult result = newOpen.ShowDialog();

       this.textBox1.Text = result + "";

    }
```

It just returns "OK"

What am I doing wrong? I wish to get the PATH to the file and display it in a text box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the filename:

```
 string filename = newOpen.FileName;
```

or filenames, if you allowed multiple file selection:

```
newOpen.FileNames;
```

Ref.: [OpenFileDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)

> ```
> private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
>     Stream myStream = null;
>     OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
>
>     openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
>     openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
>     openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
>     openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;
>
>     if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
>             {
>                 using (myStream)
>                 {
>                     // Insert code to read the stream here.
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file. Error: " + ex.Message);
>         }
>     } 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The `ShowDialog` method returns whether the user pressed `OK` or `Cancel`. This is useful information, but the actual filename is stored as a property on the dialog

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog newOpen = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult result = newOpen.ShowDialog();
        if(result == DialogResult.OK) {
              this.textBox1.Text = newOpen.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [`FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) property of the `OpenFileDialog` instance. This will get you the path of the selected file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using an existing file as a default, and getting a new file back:

```
private string open(string oldFile)
    {
        OpenFileDialog newOpen = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldFile))
        {
          newOpen.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(oldFile);
          newOpen.FileName = Path.GetFileName(oldFile);
        }

        newOpen.Filter = "eXtensible Markup Language File  (*.xml) |*.xml"; //Optional filter
        DialogResult result = newOpen.ShowDialog();
        if(result == DialogResult.OK) {
              return newOpen.FileName;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Path.GetDirectoryName(file) : Return path

Path.GetFileName(file) : Return filename